# Combining 3 datasets with a lot of columns (+100), no overlapping rows, and some unknown overlapping columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, merge, rbind

I have 3 datasets with varying rows and columns. In the end result all rows should be there, and all non-overlapping (unique) columns should be there.

```
a <- data.frame(a=c(0,1,2), b=c(3,4,5), c=c(6,7,8))
b <- data.frame(a=c(9,10,11), c=c(12,13,14), d=c(15,16,17))
```

Needs to be

```
c <- data.frame(a=c(0,1,2,9,10,11), b=c(3,4,5,NA,NA,NA), c=c(6,7,8,12,13,14), d=c(NA,NA,NA,15,16,17)
```

But imagine that instead of having abcd, you have the whole alphabet 4 times. (edit: and you don't know which ones are overlapping names (such as a and a in a and b are overlapping)).

Comment: "But imagine that instead of having abcd, you have the whole alphabet 4 times": So you have the same alphabet multiple times? Like a column named 'a' 4 or 5 times? That's not a very 'tidy' data.

Comment: No, the abcd in my dataset are represented with column names. More than 200 column names.

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of all the dplyr join commands is to join on all columns that both datasets have in common. As you want to keep all values, even when there is nothing to join on then you will want an outer join.

Probably something like the following:

```r
output = input_df1 %>%
  dplyr::outer_join(input_df2) %>%
  dplyr::outer_join(input_df3)
```

This will begin by joining the first two dataframes using all columns they have in common. Then it will join on the third dataframe using all columns in common.

This assumes that wherever dataframes have the same columns they have the same entries. Consider the following example:

```
df1:
 a | b | z
---+---+---
 1 | NA| 7

df2:
 a | b | Y
---+---+---
 1 | 2 | 8

df1:
 a | b | X
---+---+---
 1 | 2 | 9
```

This will not produce

```
output:
 a | b | z | y | x
---+---+---+---+---
 1 | 2 | 7 | 8 | 9
```

Because the first table does not have the same `b` value, even though it has the same `a` value. Instead this will produce:

```
output:
 a | b | z | y | x
---+---+---+---+---
 1 | 2 | NA| 8 | 9
 1 | NA| 7 | NA| NA
```

It you need to handle this type of case, you will have to put more effort into your joins. Perhaps start with:

```r
colnames1 = colnames(input_df1)
colnames2 = colnames(input_df2)

common_colnames = colnames1[colnames1 %in% colnames2]
```

To get all common column names and decide from there how to join.